# Using cs2n tool in Nemerle

Tags: antlr, nemerle

I am using Nemerle on VS2010. I wish to convert some c sharp code to nemerle sources

How to install cs2n on windows ?

I checked the tutorials but the way of using ANTLR is also not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CS2N is not a very good tool. It is unmaintained and has poor C# support. There is little use for it, because the Nemerle compiler can read C# code as is.

Answer (score 1):

The Nemerle includes the [PegGrammar macro](http://rsdn.ru/article/nemerle/PegGrammar-en.xml). This is a parser generator macro in many respects superior to ANTLR. Use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no working tool now.

You have AstConverter here: https://github.com/rsdn/nemerle/tree/master/snippets/csharp-parser/CSharpToNemerle

You can write some code which writes Nemerle code output.